# RewriteCond for url with parameters

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've got a problem to rewrite an url.
I want this :

```
http://www.foo.com/test.php?u=s1&id=12345&img=12
```

to

```
http://app.foo.com/12345-s1-12.test
```

First parameter u is a string, parameters id and img are integers.

I've started with something like that :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test.php?u=(.*)&id=(.*)&img=(.*)/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://app.foo.com/%2-%1-%3.test [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Thanks :)

**EDIT :**

Still doesn't work but i'm close!

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^u=(.*)&id=(.*)&img=(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://app.foo.com/%2-%1-%3.test [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Now it give me that link :

```
http://app.foo.com/12345-s1-12.test?u=s1&id=12345&img=12
```

Instead of :

```
http://app.foo.com/12345-s1-12.test
```

:(

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Solved!

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/test.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^u=(.*)&id=(.*)&img=(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://app.foo.com/%2-%1-%3.test? [R=301,L]
```

Placing a `?` on the end of the RewriteRule removes previous query string information.

Comment: On Apache 2.4 you can use the `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag instead of appending `?` (an empty query string) to the end of the _substitution_ string.

Answer (score -1):

This works perfectly! I used this - but i'm wondering why the target url shows "%3f" at the end.

I'm using:

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/ie/xx/yy.php [NC]
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^rubric=(.*)&nr=(.*)
   RewriteRule (.*) https://www.newdom.com/xx/yy.php?rubric=%1&nr=%2 [R=301,L]
```

Why is %3f at the end?