# URL re-direction using re-write rule not working for apache

Tags: apache

I have a url which is like `https://domain name/secure/RapidBoard.jspaa?rapidView=848&projectKey=QEFASD`

and this needs to be redirected to

```
https://<different domainname>/secure/RapidBoard.jspa?projectKey=FIFAASD
```

Tried many options but no success. Pls help

Comment: Sometimes it's helpful if you provide some snippets of examples of what you have tried and also where. Are you doing this in an .htaccess file or in the httpd.conf or in another .conf file?

Comment: I am trying with httpd.conf

Comment: Also I tried below

Comment: RewriteRule ^/secure/RapidBoard.jspa?rapidView=848&projectKey=QEFASD https://xx.xx.com/secure/RapidBoard.jspa?projectKey=FIFAASD

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to decipher exactly what you need and Apache rewrites are generally a pain to deal with anyway without being able to do some trial and error testing on the fly.

You'll probably want to do a condition based off the query string, similar to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^rapidView=(.*)&projectKey=(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.foo.com/secure/RapidBoard.jspa?projectKey=%2 [R=301,L]
```

You should be able to find similar examples all over the place:

- [Various Stack posts about mod_rewrite with query params](http://apache%20rewrite%20with%20parameters%20site:stackoverflow.com)
- [RewriteCond for url with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234005/rewritecond-for-url-with-parameters)

You can also do some basic testing here:
[htaccess tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=8047698f-6d43-57dd-b960-04bfe420a33e)

I plugged in the above rewrite rule in the tester to verify that it might actually work for you.

Comment: Thank you very much Russel .. That solution worked great . Appreciate your help ...

Comment: Please choose this as the accepted answer if it fulfilled your needs. Thank you!