# Redirecting URL with paramter to top-level domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, wpml, lang

I have been trying to search but no luck yet. Found different options about redirecting but nothing like what I'm looking for.

So currently the website URLs contain `lang` parameter like `?lang=en`, `?lang=ru`, `?lang=fi`. Parameters are on the very end of the URL.

Idea is to move languages to top level domain. So basically I'm looking for a way to redirect all URLs that contain parameter `?lang=ru` to top-level `.ru` domain. Same with other languages.

Can I do it via `.htaccess` or it shouldn't be done at all? Moving site to different domains should need redirection to pass the link juice and authority to new domains.

Hopefully, someone can lead me to the correct way of doing it.

Much appreciated!

Comment: https://perishablepress.com/redirect-query-string-htaccess/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234005/rewritecond-for-url-with-parameters

Comment: Thanks for the links! Got some more information. No examples to redirect same page to different top-level domain. So removing parameter and moving to new top-level domain. I will try to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: Can these URLs contain other URL parameters that you want to preserve?

Comment: No, the new URL will be without parameters and each language on top-level domain. I just need to make sure that redirect will be correctly in place from old urls to new ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no other URL parameters that need to be preserved then you can do it like the following using mod_rewrite near the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect "/foo?lang=xx" to "example.xx/foo"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=([a-z]{2})$
RewriteRule ^ https://example.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [QSD,R=302,L]
```

The above matches *any* language code that consists of 2 lowercase letters. To match specific language codes then use *alternation* in the regex and change the `RewriteCond` directive to read:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=(en|ru|fi|abc|etc)$
```

The `QSD` flag discards the original `lang=xx` query string from the redirect response (Apache 2.4). Otherwise this will be copied onto the target URL by default.

The `%1` backreference contains the value of the `lang` URL parameter captured in the preceding *condition*. The `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the full URL-path (no query string) from the request.

This does assume that the language specific TLD domains are hosted elsewhere. In other words, we do not need to check whether we are already at the required TLD domain.

Test with a 302 (temporary) redirect and only change to a 301 (permanent) redirect - if that is the intention - once you have confirmed that this works OK.

---

**UPDATE:** Any specific redirects, eg. `lang=en` to `.com` will need to appear first. For example:

```
# Redirect languages to .com
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=(en)$
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [QSD,R=302,L]

# All other language codes...
# Redirect "/foo?lang=xx" to "example.xx/foo"
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=([a-z]{2})$
RewriteRule ^ https://example.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [QSD,R=302,L]
```

Use *alternation* (as mentioned above) if there are more language codes. eg. `(en|gb)`.

Comment: I've updated my answer to use regex alternation as an alternative method - this provides some validation, providing you aren't matching too many language codes.

Comment: Amazing! This is near perfect solution. The %1 backreference here has problems. The parameter is ?lang=en for english but the domain will be .com. For ?lang=fi and ?lang=ru this statement will be working, just not for en. So we probably should manually declare the domain it will be redirected to, i guess.

Comment: Ah yes, of course (I should have twigged there isn't a `.en` TLD!) - I'll update my answer.

Comment: Sir, you have saved my day! This seems to work perfectly fine. One thing is that current main site is in Estonian and on .com domain.This is main language on .com domain which can be changed but then the URL would change as well. It has no ?lang parameter. Is there good way to redirect all .com links without parameter to .ee domain? Your are angel! Thanks!

Comment: The problem there is that it would conflict with URLs with `lang=en` that also redirect to `.com` without a `?lang` parameter? (So, `?lang=en` would end up being redirected twice and end up at `.ee` TLD.)  You say the "URL would change" - how would it change? Maybe it's possible to construct an exception to the rule?

Comment: If the _default_ language on `.com` domain is Estonian then how do you intend to set the site language to English when being redirected from `?lang=en`? Or do you not?

Comment: Yes, your solution helps a lot and works great! Redirections are always confusing for me. I'm confused about this as well. The main language and domain are currently switched. Estonian should on .ee domain while English is already redirected then to .com domain. So there is no redirection for Estonian. Main URL is without parameter.

Comment: Are there any ways to redirect default language links which does not have any param in URL? I think we are missing out default language with this solution.

Comment: Yes, you can redirect based on the absence of the `lang` URL param. What is the domain/hostname in this instance? However, the "problem" with what we have above is that `lang=en` is redirected to `example.com` and the `lang` URL param is removed. But you say that accessing `example.com` without a `lang` URL param currently displays Estonian, not English. You can't redirect `example.com` without a `lang` URL param to `example.ee` since you will then also redirect the already redirected request that originally contained `lang=en`.

Comment: If Estonian is supposed to be at `example.ee` then you could perhaps redirect all `.com` requests (with a `lang` URL param) to `example.ee`. Do not (at least for now) redirect `lang=en` to `example.com` and maybe implement this later? OR, keep the `lang=en` URL param when redirecting to `example.com` and use this to determine the language - but be mindful of the domain being redirected _from_ and where these domains resolve in order to avoid a redirect loop.

Comment: Thank you for the input! I seriously appreciate it. I don't want to spam my site, you can find the domain from my profile if its any help. I'm getting confused myself by this. Above solution is correct but i think we are missing out Estonian language. I will change site setup via WPML to put language per domain, so .com should not become problem. We would just need to redirect old links from google to new ones. As default language is Estonian its on the main .com domain without any param. So I think those would need to be redirect as well but more complicated without param.

Comment: With above solution we are redirecting all lang=en parameter links to .com domain. How could we redirect from .com domain to .ee if there is no param? It should not create any redirect loop because from and where locations are different.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this via .hataccess. You can use the code below in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} lang=en
RewriteRule ^ https//wwww.yourwebsite.ext [L,R]
```

I think it should work fine if you write same for all the others. DO give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Tested it but no effect right now. It should give permanent redirect to all links with lang=en parameter and redirect them to same page just another top-level domain, right? I'm a bit confused here as I been searching for a while.